# Difference between sharing a Dockerfile and a Docker image?

Tags: git, docker, repository, docker-registry, organization

I am trying to get a good understanding of Docker best practices and to clarify what is the difference between:

1. sharing the `Dockerfile` (specs/build configuration) including language specific config file (such as `requirements.txt` for Python or `package.json` for Node ).

and

2. creating and sharing a Docker image via a registry (e.g Docker Hub) ?

In the first case the user needs to clone the repo to get the specs and run the `docker build` to create an image.

**_**

What would be the general best practice for storing and sharing  "Docker code" (for the lack of better term) when getting started with Docker or working on personal projects?

In which situation would it be preferred to share a built image via the registry?

Comment: If I used your application then I'd prefer to have access to both the images and the specs supposing that your images are correctly tagged and are static (e.g. once a new image is released it never changes). If I want to use a pre-release build or just hack at teh codez then I'd clone the specs and hack at it then build my hackity-hack-hack'd image and use my own image in a deployment (after PR'ing upstream for example). I maintain [public repos](https://github.com/lazybit-ch) and [images](https://hub.docker.com/u/lazybit).

Comment: **Note**: if I only get access to the image you can expect me to inspect the image including but not limited too going through any source code or scripts that might be available inside any of the image layers (in case you're trying to release public images for private code then should make sure to provide them as compiled binaries).

Comment: masseyb when you say "have access to specs" are you referring to the git repo `Dockerfile`, `requirements.txt`, etc. ?

Comment: yes, access to everything that I’d need to build the image.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you masseyb!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Pushing the [`image`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) to a public repository would enable others to [`pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) the built `image` and [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) it. Providing access to the source code and [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) would enable others to [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the image locally. They're not mutually exclusive.

---

For example, I release public images to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/lazybit/actions-runner) for running [self-hosted GitHub Actions Runners](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) in Kubernetes. The releases are done using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) from the public [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lazybit-ch/actions-runner). I plan on supporting [released versions (`tag`ged builds from a `git tag`)](https://hub.docker.com/r/lazybit/actions-runner/tags) (i.e. if someone installs a released version and reports an issue) but at the same time everything is available for people to hack at it if they want too (+1 for [opensource](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source)) without limits on what you're allowed to do ([MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)) - say you wanted to add some `apt` packages to the runner image, just do eeet then build and use your own image (... and if it makes sense for other users then maybe consider creating a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) with the changes).

You [might be able to host a public repository with a proprietary license but would need to confirm the legality](https://github.community/t/usage-of-proprietary-license-in-public-repository/11219).

You can definitely host a private repository and release public images but beware that if you're trying to hide your `codez` then you should expect people like me to [`inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) your `image` if I get my hands on it so I'd suggest building compiled binaries (i.e. `go` program built [`FROM scratch`](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch)).

You can also definitely host private repos and release your images to a [private docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) then control access to your images (i.e. distribute a [`docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) configured with your private images and require that customer [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) to `pull` the images).

Comment: You can also have a mix of all of the above of course. I also maintain fully private repositories and image releases under my [lazybit-ch](https://github.com/lazybit-ch) organization.